# Trying to get description from another table on my report

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)

Dim strResultDesc As String

strResultDesc = DLookup("Description", "[products/stock]", "[Product Code] = Me.txtResultPC.Value")

Text20.Value = strResultDesc

End Sub
```

This is the code I have at the moment, I get an error saying there is an issue with:

```
[Product Code] = Me.txtResultPC.Value
```

Can anyone spot anything?

UPDATE:

Also tried this approach,

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)

Dim strResultDesc As String

strResultDesc = DLookup("Description", "[products/stock]", "[products/stock].[Product Code] = [Result PC]")

Me.Text20.Value = strResultDesc

End Sub
```

Thanks,

Bob P

Answer (score 0):

You must put symbol "&". Please see example on below.

```
strResultDesc = DLookup("Description", "[products/stock]", "[Product Code] =" & Me.txtResultPC.Value)
```

Comment: Won't work at all without the square brackets, I just get "The expression you entered as a query parameter returned this error 'produts'"

Comment: This query return string right? Ok im wrong, please put ' ' in you condition..But don`t forget remove [] in product/stock.. Example `DLookup("Description", "products/stock", "[Product Code] ='" & Me.txtResultPC.Value & "'")`

Comment: SELECT Description FROM [products/stock] WHERE (this needs to get a value from the form, but essentially it is a stored product code, stored as Result PC) = [products/stock].[Product Code]